# Embedding Cordova app inside Native Android APP

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, cordova-plugins, embedding

I know there are tons of Q&As out there, but none to my specific problem.

I've been tasked to integrate two apps, and specifically, a cordova app, that is: Rocket.Chat.Cordova (https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.Cordova), within our native Android App.

Our native MainActivity has a viewPager with four (fragments) tabs, one of these is the one to bereplaced with the cordova app, that is to replace our actual native chat with the cordova Rocket Chat one.

I know how to embed a SystemWebView in a native activity, which I managed to do , but when the embedding applies to a bigger native app, things get messy. How am I supposed to proceed? The cordova app has tons of plugins and libraries and the build.gradle is quite hard to understand (same thing is the Manifest). Any hint on where to place each cordova app's file inside the native project?

Comment: I was involved in an "emerging" two apps kind of project and we used the Apache Cordova plugin. But we end up doing everything native without any web js based frameworks such as cordova. https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/adding-native-functionality/android-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/